# How to build a project that has no change?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build

I want my project to build every time I press F5 even if the code has no change.

I searched the internet and in options I set "On Run, when projects are out of date" to "always build" and uncheck "only build startup projects and ...". but the problem didnt solved,

Any IDEA?

the main problem was this:

I have a pre-build event in my project.

The problem is when I make a change in referenced project, because my project has not changed,it does not build so does not execute the pre-build.

Comment: What does the pre-build do?  Have you tried using a Custom Build Step?

Comment: I know nothing about "Custom Build Step". Is that an alternative for pre-build?!

Comment: It's an alternative depending on what your step needs to do.  For example, I have a project that contains a custom build step that copies some files to another location.  It executes **every time** even when the source does not need to be built.